# OnScroll doesn't return expected output in android

Tags: android, listview

I add an OnScrollListener in a listView which contains 26 items.

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if(mCurrentPosition == firstVisibleItem){
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(firstVisibleItem);
}
```

When i scroll the list quickly(faster) onScroll doesn't call for every item. But when i scroll normally it's working fine.

## abnormal output:

```
System.out(30562): 0
System.out(30562): 1
System.out(30562): 2
System.out(30562): 5
System.out(30562): 8
System.out(30562): 11
System.out(30562): 14
System.out(30562): 18
System.out(30562): 20
System.out(30562): 23
System.out(30562): 26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is expected to happen. As per the documentation `onScroll` is:

**Callback method to be invoked when the list or grid has been scrolled. This will be called after the scroll has completed**

So it's called only after your scroll is completed, hence when you scroll slow all the items are called for but when you scroll fast only those items are called which are currently visible after the scroll completes.

Comment: Is there any way that i can get callback when firstVisibleItem is changed. I am trying to implementing a sticky header list view. I need to know the callback to update the topmost header.

Comment: @shantanu This event is triggered whenever you scroll your listview and whenever you do that your firstVisibleItem changes.